# Path Variable not mapping Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, path-variables

So i have the following problem. I have a controller which i mapped to "/reservationQuery/*". Whenerver i go on the url for "delete_1" method, it works, but whnever i try and go on the "delete_2" method it says that there was no mapping for that URI. But why does that happen? Shouldn all URI beggining with /reservationQuery/ be mapped by my ReservationQueryController?

And if i want to use the second URI for deletion, do i have to make another controller and map it to /reservationQuery/delete/* ?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reservationQuery/*")
public class ReservationQueryController{
private ReservationService reservationService;

@Autowired
public ReservationQueryController(ReservationService reservationService) {
    this.reservationService = reservationService;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/reservationQuery/{reservationID}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String delete_1(@PathVariable("reservationID") int reservationID, Model model){
    reservationService.deleteReservation(reservationID);
    return "reservationQuery";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/reservationQuery/delete/{reservationID}",     method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String delete_2(@PathVariable("reservationID") int reservationID, Model model){
    reservationService.deleteReservation(reservationID);
    return "reservationQuery";
}




}
```

Comment: Can you print the whole URL

Comment: I think you should be using a RequestMapping at the class level and Paths at the method level with the path appending extra onto the original URL defined in the RequestMapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the extra value of "reservationQuery" in the method level as you have already mapped "reservationQuery" in the Controller, which is the class level.

So what's happening is that at delete your URL is going to begin with /reservationQuery/reservationQuery/.

I think that's the reason for an error and it should be HTTP Error 404

Answer (score 2):

You should map your controller with `"/reservationQuery"` and your method `delete_1` should be mapped with `"/{reservationID}"` and method `delete_2` should be mapped with `"/delete/{reservationID}"`. There is no need to repeat controller mapping in methods.

Comment: IMHO, it is a neater solution than the one proposed by jorrin, because you factorize the upper part of the URL at controller level.